# Capture photo and record video on same view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, video-capture

I have trouble figuring out, how to capture photo and record video on same view because methods used for both are same.
I tried it but still not clear whether code is correct or not.

I shall be thankful if someone would just review the code and tell me it's correct or not.

Below is the code :

```
 - (IBAction)CaptureRubbish:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)RecordRubbish:(id)sender {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) { 
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        picker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}


- (void)videoPlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];

    // Stop the video player and remove it from view
    [self.videoController stop];
    [self.videoController.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.videoController = nil;

    // Display a message
    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Video Playback" message:@"Just finished the video playback. The video is now removed." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *okayAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
    [alertController addAction:okayAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self->ImageVIew.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    self.videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    self.videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

    [self.videoController setContentURL:self.videoURL];
    [self.videoController.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 460)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.videoController.view];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.videoController];
    [self.videoController play];

}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info { } in this method you have write code for photo and for video with put one if condition

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya what should i put in if-else condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
   if (info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] == (NSString *) kUTTypeImage) {
     // here your image capture code
   }
   else if(info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType]== (NSString *)kUTTypeMovie)
   {
      // here your video capture code
   }
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: this answer for objective c